# Creating a new array by comparing data from other arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, if-statement

I currently have 3 arrays (36 x 36), and I now want to create a forth that compares the original three arrays and plots a set value depending on which array has largest value in said cell. The easiest way I can think to explain this is as follows.

Say I have the arrays;

```
a = [10,20,30]
    [15,20,18]

b = [0,10,70] 
    [36,67,9]

c = [0,50,20]
    [100,4,45]
```

I want to create a new array that will plot 1 when 'a' is has the largest value, 2 when b is largest and  3 when c has the largest value.

So the new array should look something like this;

```
new_array = [1,3,2]
            [3,2,3]
```

I know this is probably a very simple loop but I am not very proficient in Python and could use a hand.

Comment: What is `a = [10,20,30] [15,20,18]` supposed to represent? It's not a valid literal, and it's unclear what kind of pseudo data structure it's supposed to be.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your arrays. Based on your question I think they are arrays of arrays. So like a = [[10,20,30], [15,20,18]]. Note the extra bracket.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Could you post a minimal example of what you've done so far, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with loops, you can just do something like this

```
new_array = [[0 for x in range(36)] for y in range(36)] 

for i in range(36):
  for j in range(36):
    if (a[i][j] >= b[i][j] and a[i][j] >= c[i][j]):
      new_array[i][j] = 1
    elif (b[i][j] >= a[i][j] and b[i][j] >= c[i][j]):
      new_array[i][j] = 2
    else:
      new_array[i][j] = 3
```

Comment: Thanks sedrick that was the method that I was initially trying to use, I was failing to repeat the argument after the 'and'. So I was doing;   if a[i][j] > b and c. Thanks for clearing this up!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your arrays are actually valid numpy arrays like so:

```py
a = [[10,20,30],
     [15,20,18]]

b = [[0,10,70] ,
     [36,67,9]]

c = [[0,50,20],
     [100,4,45]]
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
c = np.array(c)
```

You could use

```py
np.argmax(np.stack([a, b, c], axis=0), axis=0) + 1

>>> array([[1, 3, 2],
           [3, 2, 3]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the built-in `max()` and `tuple.index()`, along with `zip()` to group corresponding elements into a tuple and then find the original list that each element came from:

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 15, 20, 18]
b = [0, 10, 70, 36, 67, 9]
c = [0, 50, 20, 100, 4, 45] 

new_array = [(tup.index(max(tup)) + 1) for tup in zip(a, b, c)]
# [1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]
```

This solution is easily extensible to more lists (just add more to the `zip()` call) and to multidimensional lists (just nest the list comprehension accordingly).